# How can I get a list of posts as sub-items of authors in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, html-lists

How can I list posts as sub-items of authors? It should look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Author</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Post1</li>
            <li>Post2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have an array containing author data including `$author->ID`. This comes from `get_users()`.
My function looks like this:

```
function add_custom_menu_items($items, $args) {

    $authors = get_users('role=author'); \\Returns array of author meta-data.

    return $items.$authors_str;    
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_custom_menu_items', 5, 2);
```

Where can I get a list of posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [`wp query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) to query posts for each author:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'author=123' );
```

or

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'author_name=rami' );
```

and loop through each post like:

```
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```